# Mongoose asynchronous population error. Not calling method properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

So I am messing with populations in mongoose. The original [example](https://raw.github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/master/examples/population/population-basic.js) they had was horrible. It returned the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
at Promise.<anonymous> (/home/kevin/LearnMongoose/population/population-basic.js:104:56)
at Promise.<anonymous> (/home/kevin/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:162:8)
at Promise.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:94:17)
at Promise.emit (/home/kevin/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:79:38)
at Promise.fulfill (/home/kevin/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:92:20)
at Promise.resolve (/home/kevin/node_modules/mongoose/lib/promise.js:108:15)
at Promise.<anonymous> (/home/kevin/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:162:8)
at Promise.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:94:17)
at Promise.emit (/home/kevin/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:79:38)
at Promise.fulfill (/home/kevin/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:92:20)
```

I decided to mess around with the code to get it working. This is what the new code is.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

console.log('Running mongoose version %s', mongoose.version);

/**
 * Console schema
 */

var consoleSchema = Schema({
    name: String
  , manufacturer: String
  , released: Date
})
var Console = mongoose.model('Console', consoleSchema);

/**
 * Game schema
 */

var gameSchema = Schema({
    name: String
  , developer: String
  , released: Date
  , consoles: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Console' }]
})
var Game = mongoose.model('Game', gameSchema);

/**
 * Connect to the console database on localhost with
 * the default port (27017)
 */

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/bjank', function (err) {
  // if we failed to connect, abort
  if (err) throw err;

  // we connected ok
  createData();

})

/**
 * Data generation
 */

function createGame(){
  new Game({
     name: 'Legend of Zelda: Ocarina of Time'
      , developer: 'Nintendo'
      , released: new Date('November 21, 1998')
  }).save(function(err) {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log('The Game has been saved');
      }

  });
}

function createConsole(){
  new Console({
     name: 'Nintendo 64'
    , manufacturer: 'Nintendo'
    , released: 'September 29, 1996'
  }).save(function(err) {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log('The Console is saved');
      }

  });
}

  function pushToGame(){


    Game.findOne({name: /^Legend of Zelda/}, function (err, game){
      if(err) {return done(err);}
      console.log(game + '\n\n');
      Console.findOne({name: /^Nintendo 64/}, function  (err, consolee) {
        console.log('\n\nPulling specifed Game console\n');
        console.log(consolee);
        game.consoles.push(consolee);
        console.log('\n\nIt somehow works');
        console.log('\nThe second print of the game(should have the N64(consolee) console in the console ref array): \n\n' + game);

      })

    });
  }


  function showGame() {
    console.log('The method showGame() has started\n\n\n\n\n');
    Game.findOne({name: /^Legend of Zelda/}), function  (err, game) {
      console.log('This is not working');
      console.log(game);
  }

  }

function createData () {
  createGame();
  createConsole();
  pushToGame();
  showGame(); 

}


function done (err) {
  if (err) console.error(err);
  Console.remove(function () {
    Game.remove(function () {
      mongoose.disconnect();
    })
  })
}
```

It returned the result in the command line:

```
The method showGame() has started


{ name: 'Legend of Zelda: Ocarina of Time',
  developer: 'Nintendo',
  released: Sat Nov 21 1998 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST),
  _id: 5208628ddbc8cf1302000001,
  __v: 0,
  consoles: [] }


The Game has been saved
The Console is saved


Pulling specifed Game console

{ name: 'Nintendo 64',
  manufacturer: 'Nintendo',
  released: Sun Sep 29 1996 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT),
  _id: 5208628ddbc8cf1302000002,
  __v: 0 }


It somehow works

The second print of the game(should have the N64(consolee) console in the console ref array): 

{ name: 'Legend of Zelda: Ocarina of Time',
  developer: 'Nintendo',
  released: Sat Nov 21 1998 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST),
  _id: 5208628ddbc8cf1302000001,
  __v: 0,
  consoles: [ 5208628ddbc8cf1302000002 ] }
```

It didn't break when I made some modifications but as you can see I placed a lot of console logs to see what was happening throughout the script. The line:

> The method showGame() has started

is supposed to be at the end and not the beginning, because that's the order I called the function.

I have no idea why this is not working, because it should, but it's not. Why is my showGame() function getting called before I even create my data even when it's called after the create data is called?

**Additional Info**

I somewhat know of the structure of Node.js. I know that it works asynchronously. Maybe the showGame function ran first because the First few functions were being too slow. If that's the case, how can I queue the showGame() function to be last with this type of structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using the `createData()` method, you should call every function after the previous method's callback, if there are no errors. For example :

```
function createGame(){
  new Game({
     name: 'Legend of Zelda: Ocarina of Time'
      , developer: 'Nintendo'
      , released: new Date('November 21, 1998')
  }).save(function(err) {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      else {
        console.log('The Game has been saved');
        createConsole()
      }
  });
}
```

There is also the more verbose and uglier solution :

```
function createData () {
  createGame(function(error) {
    if(error) {
        throw error;
    }
    else {
        createConsole(function(err) {
            if(err) {
                throw err;
            }
            else {
                pushToGame(function(er) {
                    if(er) {
                        throw er;
                    }
                    else {
                        showGame(function(e) {
                            if(e) {
                                throw e;
                            }
                            else {
                                // rest of your code
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: So that got my stuff to sychrnously work, but for some reason the second findOne function in showGame doesn't. I pretty much copied and pasted the function from pushToGame() which did work, therefore I have no idea why that didn't work out.

Comment: So I fixed it. I was embedding the function in the wrong place. It now works! Thank you